# Load bearing or not load bearing?

Tags: walls, kitchens, removal, load

We are in the process of removing a wall between our kitchen and living area. House is one level. Had someone already come out to inspect and he said it was not load bearing but wondering if we need a second opinion. Trusses run parallel with the wall we are removing. The truss sit a few inches off from where the framing is. [image][image][image]

Comment: You're looking at the top of the wall. Are there any loads bearing on top of it? Typically blocking is installed across ceiling elements (like the bottom chords of your trusses) to anchor a wall against toppling, so such blocking doesn't count.